# How to check if the JSObjectRef object is an array?

Tags: javascriptcore

In javascriptcore, we can generate an array object using this code:

```
JSObjectRef array = JSObjectMakeArray(ctx, 0, NULL, NULL)
```

There're also functions like `JSObjectMakeString`/`JSObjectMakeNumber` to generate JSObjectRef objects, so when using an object, I cannot find a method such as JSObjectIsArray to check the object type, but it does have JSValueIsString/JSValueIsNumber method under `JSValueRef`.

so how to check whether the obj is an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if an object is an array with JavaScript you can use `Array.isArray(obj)` (for browsers that support it), like JavaScriptCore implement it, you can write your own `JSValueIsArray` function, like this :

```
bool JSValueIsArray(JSContextRef ctx, JSValueRef value)
{
    if (JSValueIsObject(ctx, value))
    {
        JSStringRef name = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("Array");

        JSObjectRef array = (JSObjectRef)JSObjectGetProperty(ctx, JSContextGetGlobalObject(ctx), name, NULL);

        JSStringRelease(name);

        name = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("isArray");
        JSObjectRef isArray = (JSObjectRef)JSObjectGetProperty(ctx, array, name, NULL);

        JSStringRelease(name);

        JSValueRef retval = JSObjectCallAsFunction(ctx, isArray, NULL, 1, &value, NULL);

        if (JSValueIsBoolean(ctx, retval))
            return JSValueToBoolean(ctx, retval);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Emmanuel, I got another question: if the object is an array, how to get elements from it? thanks!

Comment: How about https://developer.apple.com/documentation/javascriptcore/1395924-jsvalueisarray

Comment: @Maruku It's iOS 9+, so this solution is for backwards compatibility with iOS 8 and earlier.

Answer (score 3):

I found some other operations for array, I'd like to paste the code here to help others.

**get array length:**

```
int JSArrayGetCount(JSContextRef ctx, JSObjectRef arr)
{
    JSStringRef pname = JSStringCreateWithUTF8CString("length");
    JSValueRef val = JSObjectGetProperty(ctx, arr, pname, NULL);
    JSStringRelease(pname);
    return JSValueToNumber(ctx, val, NULL);
}
```

**get array element by index:**

```
JSValueRef JSArrayGetValueAtIndex(JSContextRef ctx, JSObjectRef arr, int index)
{
    return JSObjectGetPropertyAtIndex(ctx, arr, index, NULL);
}
```